# Install postgresql on fedora 16 for use with Rails3

Tags: postgresql, fedora, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install posgresql on F16 to work with my rails installation.  Using this guide

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation#Initialize

But when I run `service postgresql initdb` I get this error

> Unknown operation initdb

Answer (score 2):

Fedora 16 has migrated to `systemd` from traditional init.d layout, so you should run `su - postgres -c "PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/data initdb"` directly, see [Fedora wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji/ServerHowTo#PostgreSQL_Server)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the link you provide it says

```
For PostgreSQL version 9.0 and above, the <name> is postgresql-9.0...
```

and later is says

```
service <name> initdb
```

so I'm guessing you want

```
service postgresql-9.0 initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use `sudo postgresql-setup initdb`.